# the file does not match your project config: src\index.html

Tags: typescript, tslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to upgrade TSLint to ESLint but having below error:

> 0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for
> @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project
> config: src\index.html. The extension for the file (.html) is
> non-standard. You should add "parserOptions.extraFileExtensions" to
> your config

I tried other answers related to this one but no luck.

Here is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [],
  ignorePatterns: ['projects/**/*', '/*.*'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  // other rules ....
}
```

What can be the possible solution for this, if I want to exclude the `.html` extension.